# Writing a DTrace consumer in C

Tags: c, freebsd, dtrace

I'd like to write a C program on FreeBSD 10.1 that implements a *DTrace consumer* using `libdtrace`.

I know that I need to start with a call to `dtrace_open()` - e.g. I have found [this](http://www.osdevcon.org/2008/files/osdevcon2008-petr.pdf) old presentation, but I can't get even started, since there is no `dtrace.h` installed (only in the system source tree).

The shared library is installed, e.g. the `/usr/sbin/dtrace` tool included with FreeBSD can act as a DTrace consumer and this tool links to `/lib/libdtrace.so.2` (which is also pointed to via a symbolic link from `/usr/lib/libdtrace.so`).

Any basic example, including build instructions (FreeBSD 10.1 / clang) will help me a lot.

---

**The actual goal of writing a custom consumer is creating a [CFFI](https://cffi.readthedocs.org/) based wrapper usable in Python and [PyPy](http://pypy.org/).** Means: above C program is just to get started, learn and then proceed.

CFFI is the recommended, modern, high-performance way of interfacing PyPy with shared libraries.

CFFI can be used at the [ABI](https://cffi.readthedocs.org/en/release-0.8/#simple-example-abi-level) and API level. The latter requires a header file to include, the former requires to declare the stuff used from a lib.

---

**Adapted from Adam's answer, here is a complete example that works on FreeBSD 10.1.**

`Makefile`:

```
all:
        cc \
         -I /usr/src/cddl/compat/opensolaris/include \
         -I /usr/src/cddl/contrib/opensolaris/lib/libdtrace/common/ \
         -I /usr/src/sys/cddl/compat/opensolaris \
         -I /usr/src/sys/cddl/contrib/opensolaris/uts/common/ \
         hello_dtrace.c \
         -l dtrace -l proc -l ctf -l elf -l z -l rtld_db -l pthread -l util \
         -o hello_dtrace
```

`hello_dtrace.c`:

```
#include <dtrace.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static dtrace_hdl_t* g_dtp;

static int chewrec (const dtrace_probedata_t *data, const dtrace_recdesc_t *rec, void *arg) {
   printf("chewing dtrace record ..\n");
   // A NULL rec indicates that we've processed the last record.
   if (rec == NULL) {
      return (DTRACE_CONSUME_NEXT);
   }
   return (DTRACE_CONSUME_THIS);
}

static const char* g_prog = "BEGIN { printf(\"hello from dtrace\\n\"); }";
//static const char* g_prog = "syscall::open*:entry { printf(\"%s %s\\n\", execname, copyinstr(arg0)); }";

static int g_intr;
static int g_exited;

static void intr (int signo) {
   g_intr = 1;
}


int main (int argc, char** argv) {
   int err;

   if ((g_dtp = dtrace_open(DTRACE_VERSION, 0, &err)) == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "failed to initialize dtrace: %s\n", dtrace_errmsg(NULL, err));
      return -1;
   }
   printf("Dtrace initialized\n");

   (void) dtrace_setopt(g_dtp, "bufsize", "4m");
   (void) dtrace_setopt(g_dtp, "aggsize", "4m");
   printf("dtrace options set\n");

   dtrace_prog_t* prog;
   if ((prog = dtrace_program_strcompile(g_dtp, g_prog, DTRACE_PROBESPEC_NAME, 0, 0, NULL)) == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "failed to compile dtrace program\n");
      return -1;
   } else {
      printf("dtrace program compiled\n");
   }

   dtrace_proginfo_t info;
   if (dtrace_program_exec(g_dtp, prog, &info) == -1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "failed to enable dtrace probes\n");
      return -1;
   } else {
      printf("dtrace probes enabled\n");
   }

   struct sigaction act;
   (void) sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
   act.sa_flags = 0;
   act.sa_handler = intr;
   (void) sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL);
   (void) sigaction(SIGTERM, &act, NULL);

   if (dtrace_go(g_dtp) != 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "could not start instrumentation\n");
      return -1;
   } else {
      printf("instrumentation started ..\n");
   }

   int done = 0;
   do {
      if (!g_intr && !done) {
         dtrace_sleep(g_dtp);
      }

      if (done || g_intr || g_exited) {
         done = 1;
         if (dtrace_stop(g_dtp) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "could not stop tracing\n");
            return -1;
         }
      }

      switch (dtrace_work(g_dtp, stdout, NULL, chewrec, NULL)) {
         case DTRACE_WORKSTATUS_DONE:
            done = 1;
            break;
         case DTRACE_WORKSTATUS_OKAY:
            break;
         default:
            fprintf(stderr, "processing aborted");
            return -1;
      }
   } while (!done);

   printf("closing dtrace\n");
   dtrace_close(g_dtp);

   return 0;
}
```

To run:

```
[oberstet@brummer2 ~/hello_dtrace]$ make; sudo ./hello_dtrace
cc  -I /usr/src/cddl/contrib/opensolaris/lib/libdtrace/common/  -I /usr/src/sys/cddl/compat/opensolaris  -I /usr/src/sys/cddl/contrib/opensolaris/uts/common/  hello_dtrace.c  -l dtrace  -l proc  -l ctf  -l elf  -l rtld_db  -l z  -l pthread  -l util  -o hello_dtrace
Dtrace initialized
dtrace options set
dtrace program compiled
dtrace probes enabled
instrumentation started ..
chewing dtrace record ..
hello from dtrace
chewing dtrace record ..
^Cclosing dtrace
```

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but you might try https://wiki.freebsd.org/DTrace. There are examples of code there.

Comment: Thanks, I've read these, but it doesn't disclose how to write a custom consumer in C.

Comment: Sorry to be so pedantic, but did you also read the link from that site on https://wiki.freebsd.org/DTrace/KernelSupport. There are instructions for additional `make buildworld` that I think will pull in the support files you're looking for.

Comment: "as of May 2012, DTrace support is enabled by default in GENERIC, and the steps below are not needed" - I am running 10.1 Release (which does have DTrace builtin by default)

Comment: @oberstet:I think you can try to help from DTrace mailing list: [http://dtrace.org/blogs/mailing-list/](http://dtrace.org/blogs/mailing-list/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `libdtrace` API isn't necessarily intended for stable consumers, but it's pretty easy to learn from some existing consumers to get started. The simplest and most modern is [`plockstat`](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/31c6d826a7f7a4ee7d83c8e99f25d82a4a248076/usr/src/cmd/plockstat/plockstat.c), the illumos utility for user-land locking statistics.

Here's the basic flow of a simple DTrace consumer program:

`dtrace_open()` to get a dtrace_hdl_t, a handle for other `libdtrace` interactions
`dtrace_setopt()` to configure options (`-x` flag to `dtrace(1M)`)
`dtrace_strcompile()` to compile a string of your D program
`dtrace_program_exec()` to send that program to the kernel
`dtrace_go()` to instrument the system and start recording data
`dtrace_close()` to clean up at the end

For the main data collection loop (between `dtrace_go()` and `dtrace_close()`) do the following:

`dtrace_sleep()` to pause according to the DTrace options (switchrate and aggrate)
`dtrace_work()` to process traced data
`dtrace_stop()` to abort

See the main loop in [`plockstat.c`](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/31c6d826a7f7a4ee7d83c8e99f25d82a4a248076/usr/src/cmd/plockstat/plockstat.c#L971) for more.

For other simple DTrace consumers, check out [`intrstat`](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/31c6d826a7f7a4ee7d83c8e99f25d82a4a248076/usr/src/cmd/intrstat/intrstat.c) and [`lockstat`](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/31c6d826a7f7a4ee7d83c8e99f25d82a4a248076/usr/src/cmd/lockstat/lockstat.c). For the kitchen sink, check out the code the the dtrace(1M) command-line utility.

Comment: Awesome! I got something working on FreeBSD (added to question body). It seems, `plockstat` has the main loop blocking in `dtrace_sleep`, whereas `intrstat` sets up a high-frequency timer and blocks in `sigsuspend`. Both block the calling thread. Any hints on which approach I should follow?

Comment: Ah, and one more thing: ultimately, this will be running in a program which has an asynchronous reactor / event loop (Python Twisted/asyncio). In this context, one must never block the (main) thread (as the reactor loop wants to block itself inside a call to `select()`, `poll()` or such waiting for FDs to become ready). So I need to have the dtrace consumer loop (which blocks) running on a background thread. Any issues with that?

Answer (score 4):

dtrace is considered a system internal interface, and writing a custom consumer is not something that is supported.

The best you can do is check out a copy of the FreeBSD source tree and build your code from there. This actually isn't terribly difficult. Obviously, `dtrace(1)` is the canonical dtrace consumer, so you can look at its implementation for examples of how to use libdtrace. Additionally `dtrace.h` has a huge amount of comments explaining data structures and internals.

Building the files in the context of the source tree is pretty easy; the FreeBSD source tree layout is simple and writing Makefiles to build binaries in a self-contained manner is basically given to you "for free".

Pertinent points:

- Clone [the dtrace(1) Makefile](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/cddl/usr.sbin/dtrace/Makefile?revision=210691&view=markup) into a new directory in your source tree checkout. Modify the Makefile such that `.PATH` is correct, and set `PROG` and `SRCS` to include the set of sources comprising your custom consumer.
- Clone [dtrace.c](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/cddl/contrib/opensolaris/cmd/dtrace/dtrace.c?revision=277300&view=markup) to your source directory (whereever you pointed `.PATH` to) and make changes as needed. Although the source is nearly 2,000 lines, much of it is support code. If you're just looking to clone a subset of the functionality, you'll find that most of the options to the binary are implemented in self-contained functions, and it should therefore be fairly easy to trim `dtrace.c` down to a bare-minimum form.

Without knowing what specifically you're needing to do with your custom consumer, it's difficult to tell you what else you'll need to call into. I'm assuming you'll probably want [compile_file](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/cddl/contrib/opensolaris/cmd/dtrace/dtrace.c?revision=277300&view=markup#l754) in there as well as [exec_prog](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/cddl/contrib/opensolaris/cmd/dtrace/dtrace.c?revision=277300&view=markup#l585). Of course, your needs may differ.

The [`dtrace.h` you will be using](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/cddl/contrib/opensolaris/lib/libdtrace/common/dtrace.h?revision=277300&view=markup) has a number of comments about the various interfaces provided.

Hopefully this is enough to get you started; unfortunately, there's not a way to do what you want from a vanilla install. You could, of course, hack up the relevant Makefiles to install the necessary header files and create your own internal distribution. But that seems like more pain than it's worth.

Comment: Thank's a lot for your detailed answer. Please give me some time to try, and also because of https://twitter.com/ahl/status/557981334615126016 - I've updated the question for what my actual goals are with a custom consumer

Comment: You're welcome! I'm happy to have ahl expand on the answer / provide more insight as to what needs to be done in providing an acceptable answer. (Hi, Adam!)